# Add listbox items in form 1 from form 2 button pushed in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Form (form1) which has a ListBox and a Button. On clicking the button, it opens another Form (form2). In this Form I have a TexBox and a Button. On clicking this button, whatever I entered in this Textbox, should have to go into the ListBox in form1. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Please read more about Object Oriented Programing

Answer (score 2):

step 1 : Set the **Modifiers** property of **Listbox** as **Public**

step 2 : in button click of Form1, put

```
        Form2 fm2 = new Form2(this);
        fm2.ShowDialog();
```

step 3: in Form2, put the following declaration at top level

```
    private Form1 _fm1;

    Also add a constructor :

    public Form2(Form1 fm1)
    {
        _fm1 = fm1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

step 4: in button click of **Form2**, put the following lines:

```
 _fm1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Textbox1.Text);
  this.Close(); //close the Form2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a static instance of form1 `public static Form1 _Form1;`,then you have access it from other forms with out make an instance:

I write an example:

### Form1.cs

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Form1 = this;
        }
        public static Form1 _Form1;
        public void AddItem(object value)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(value);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Form2 _Form2 = new Form2();
          _Form2.Show();
        }
    }
```

### Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1._Form1.AddItem("your item");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Form1 the Owner of Form 2 and then you can access Form1 from Form2:

**Form1:**

```
private void Form1Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Owner = this;
f2.Show();
}

public void AddListItem(object text)
{
    YourListBox.Items.Add(text);
}
```

**Form2:**

```
private void Form2Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 f1 = (Form1)Owner;
f1.AddListItem(YourTextBox.Text;);
Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the second form pass a reference to the current form:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

In the constructor of form2 save the reference and use the reference in the click handler

```
class Form2
{
    private Form1 _form1;
    public Form2()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Form2(Form1 form1):this()
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_form1 != null)
        {
            _form1.AddValue(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be way better to define an interface that contains the method 'AddValue' and instead of using the type Form1 use the interface:

```
interface IAddValues
{
    void AddValue(string value);
}

class Form1: IAddValues
{
    // ...

    public void AddValue(string value)
    {
         // ...
    }
}

    // somewhere in form1:
    var form2 = new Form2(this as IAddValues);
    form2.Show();
```

In the constructor of form2 save the reference and use the reference in the click handler

```
class Form2
{
    private IAddValues _valueAdder;
    public Form2()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public Form2(IAddValues valueAdder):this()
    {
        _valueAdder = valueAdder;
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(_valueAdder != null)
        {
            _valueAdder.AddValue(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```